# Why Ctrl+G doesn't produce a beep?

Tags: linux

I have read that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in the terminal produces a beep sound. I have tried it and nothing happens. Why?

I am using GNOME Terminal and Bash.

Comment: That statement probably refers to a certain situation. The simple answer is probably that your system is not configured that way (and it is not the default). Is your question how you can configure this behaviour?

Comment: @Hauke Laging I didn't know that this behavior can be enabled/disabled, in that case, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> on your keyboard has your terminal emulator ***send*** the 0x7 byte, aka `^G` which in ASCII is the BEL character aka `\a` (alert).

Most terminals issue a *beep* (or visual bell, like a flashing of the screen), when they ***receive*** that character, that is when the application writes that character to the terminal device file, or when the *echo* of the tty discipline of that terminal device sends it back unmodified.

If you enter:

```
printf '\a'
```

Or:

```
printf '\7'
```

You should see a flash or hear a beep.

If not, check your terminal emulator configuration, bells may be disabled by default. You may also need to enable it globally in your desktop environment for fancy integrated terminal emulators like gnome-terminal. If that still doesn't work try with a proper terminal emulator like `xterm`.

In X11, terminal emulators (or the libraries they use) will typically call the `XBell()` standard X library function to cause a beep when they've not been configured to do screen flashing.

That beep (pitch, base volume, duration) can be configured with the `xset b` command.

On Linux and on PCs, by default, the X server will use the PC Speaker. However nowadays, the `pcspkr` is usually disabled by default.

Instead, applications can register with the X server to handle those bells. The `pulseaudio` sound server used in many desktop environments can do that.

If it's not already configured to do it, you can uncomment or add these lines to your `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` file (or `/etc/pulse/default.pa` for system-wide):

```
load-sample-lazy x11-bell /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga
load-module module-x11-bell sample=x11-bell
```

(replace the sound sample with one of your choice).

Now, to hear a beep when you press <kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd>, you'd need the application to *echo* that `^G` character. Or for applications that don't have their own line editor, have the tty device line discipline *echo* it when in `icanon` mode.

By default, the line discipline on Linux will echo it, but it will echo it as `^G` (`^` and `G` characters). That can be changed with

```
stty -echoctl
```

If you do:

```
stty -echoctl; cat
```

You'll hear the beep or see the screen flashing upon <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>. While without the `stty -echoctl` or after `stty echoctl`, you'd see `^G` being displayed upon <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>.

At the prompt of an interactive shell application like `zsh` or `bash`, or within a visual application like `vi`, `emacs`, `mutt`, `aptitude`... the application may decide to do whatever it wants upon reading that BEL/`^G` character from the terminal device file.

In `emacs` `^G` is for *aborting the current editor action*. It's the same in `zsh` or `bash` when in `emacs` mode (with `bash` or other applications using GNU `readline`, that's also affected by the `bell-style` and `prefer-visible-bell` parameters). As part of that, they do send a `^G` character back to the terminal, which should cause a beep/flash.

Some possibly relevant commands to query the current configuration (many of which only apply to GNU/Linux systems using a gtk-based desktop environment and `pulseaudio`):

- Check the terminal device line discipline `echo`-related parameters (for applications like `cat` that don't implement their own terminal user interface (TUI)):

  ```
  stty -a | grep echo
  ```
- What action is mapped to `^G` at the prompt of your shell:

  ```
  bindkey '^G' # in zsh or tcsh
  bind -p | grep C-g # in bash
  ```
- bell related settings in the GNU `readline` configuration:

  ```
  grep bell /etc/inputrc ~/.inputrc
  bind -v | grep bell # bash
  ```
- bell related settings in the `xterm` terminal emulator:

  ```
  appres XTerm | grep -i bell
  ```
- in some gtk-based terminal emulators or environments:

  ```
  gsettings list-recursively | grep -i bell
  dconf dump / | awk '/^\[/{p=$0};/bell/{print p ORS $0}'
  gconftool -R /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles | grep bell
  ```
- X11 bell configuration:

  ```
  xset q | grep bell
  ```
- bell-related configuration in pulseaudio:

  ```
  pactl list | awk -vRS= -vORS='\n\n' '/bell|pcsp/'
  ```

  <sup>(on a Linux Mint Cinnamon system here, `/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11` does a `/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-bell "display=$DISPLAY" "sample=bell.ogg"` but never defines/uploads the `bell.ogg` sample, so the bell doesn't work until you do `pactl upload-sample /usr/share/cinnamon/sounds/bell.ogg bell.ogg` for instance)</sup>
- whether the `pcspkr` or `snd-pcsp` kernel module is loaded:

  ```
  lsmod | grep pcsp
  ```
- whether they are explicitly disabled (blacklisted):

  ```
  grep -r pcsp /etc/modprobe*
  ```
- loaded but disabled?

  ```
  find /sys/module -path '*pcsp*/enable' -exec grep -H . {} +
  ```
- whether the PC speaker is available as an ALSA device:

  ```
  alsactl -f alsa.dump store; sed '/pcsp/,/^}/!d'  alsa.dump
  ```
- does `^G` sent to the Linux virtual console emit a beep?

  ```
  printf \\a | sudo tee /dev/tty0
  ```
- Does playing the `x11-bell` (assuming one is defined) emit a sound?

  ```
  pactl play-sample x11-bell
  ```
- is there an input event device registered by the `pcspkr` module?

  ```
  find /sys/class/input -lname '*/pcsp*/event*' -ls
  ```